# an odd clause from the Guardian

Tags: meaning

*If the 20th century's foulest villain was a dab hand at sunlight on stone walls, why do we still implicitly trust the beautiful?*

https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2009/apr/29/hitler-painting-art

I do not know how to deal with the interpretation of this clause. The first sentence seems to be the conditional clause but probably it is not that case because of the use of "was" instead "of" were. I really do not know what type of the clause it is and how to understand it.

Comment: Do you have a problem with making sense out of the sentence in terms of grammar or do you also have trouble understating the vocabulary used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to read the entire article and, to be perfectly honest, I'm not even sure what exactly they're talking about there, but the grammatical structure of the sentence is pretty clear-cut. Let's just get rid of *if* and use some other words instead. Here's what we get:

> Why do we still implicitly trust the beautiful **since** the 20th century's foulest villain was a dab hand at sunlight on stone walls?
>   Why do we still implicitly trust the beautiful **if it is the case that** the 20th century's foulest villain was a dab hand at sunlight on stone walls?
>   Why do we still implicitly trust the beautiful **if we all know that** the 20th century's foulest villain was a dab hand at sunlight on stone walls?
>   Why do we still implicitly trust the beautiful **despite the fact that** the 20th century's foulest villain was a dab hand at sunlight on stone walls?

Has it become a little bit clearer now? It's actually not a real conditional. The word **if** has lots of uses and meanings in English. One of them is **despite the fact that**. And that's the one we're dealing with here. Consider the following example which structurally uses the same grammatical model as your original sentence:

> Why do you still smoke **if** you know very well that it's bad for your health?

We can rewrite this sentence substituting the conjunction **if** with the phrase **despite the fact that** without messing up the semantics:

> Why do you still smoke **despite the fact that** you know very well that it's bad for your health?